# Cross validation predictor score the same

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to choose the csv file with data which has better prediction scores.
I am trying to determine cross validation scores using the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
import os,csv
from sklearn import cross_validation
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics

files = [e for e in os.listdir('.') if e.endswith('.csv')]

csvout = open('xval.csv','wb')
csvwriter=csv.writer(csvout)

for f in files:

    X,Y=[],[]
    feat=f[4:-4]
    print feat

    csvin = open(f,'rb')
    csvread=csv.reader(csvin)
    for row in csvread:
        X.append([row[0]])
        Y.append(1 if row[1]=='True' else 0)

    clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
    predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(clf, X, Y, cv=3) 
    print metrics.accuracy_score(Y, predicted)

csvout.close()
```

The two csvs are as follows, a.csv and b.csv:

```
0.8307059089237866,False
0.07933411654760168,False
0.07933411654760168,False
0.07933411654760168,False
0.07933411654760168,False
0.8050114148789536,False
0.7050883824823811,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.07933411654760168,True
0.6251499565651232,True

0.3507377775833331,False
0.2609619627153587,False
0.24483806968609972,False
0.7122564948467026,False
0.7172548646226102,False
0.1321163493448647,False
0.023658678331543205,True
0.5954080270729952,True
0.632479304055982,True
0.22412105580276065,True
0.3431509885671966,True
0.5954080270729952,True
0.1137442754294842,True
0.8312144672461341,True
0.1137442754294842,True
```

However, I am getting the exact same predictor score. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code will not work because the variable CV (number of folds) of the cross_val_predict() function is bigger than the number of samples of the class 0 (False). If you lower it to less (or equal) than 6 it will work and you'll get an accuracy of 0.6 for a.csv and 0.625 for b.csv.

Comment: I am using a bigger dataset actually. The 'Y' section is always the same. Is that why the values are the same

Comment: Ok. No, it's not the reason. The score will be the same if the _predicted_ array is the same. And it's what happened to you.

Try first to print the _predicted_ array. You'll probably notice that it is filled with 1, this is not good. Then try to have the same quantity of False and True in your dataset, this will change the accuracy score for sure.

But what you're trying to do is not really relevent, your X array must have more than one feature.

Comment: Thanks. i now noticed that predicted contains the same values. How do I get it to diversify?

Comment: The way I explained earlier : First balance you dataset, it means having the same quantity of True and False samples. Then you have to add multiple features to each sample (in the X array) instead of only one.

What are your values related to (ex : 0.3507377775833331) ? Maybe I can help you further.

Comment: i am now using two features in X. As far as Y is concerned, i am afraid it is not possible to get an equal number of trues and falses. Why values are extracting readability measures to see if it is plagiarized or not.

Comment: But can cross validation be used to see which dataset can predict True values better? My prof mentioned it to me, I dont understand why. Esp. since recall is more suitable

Comment: To know which one gives the best result, you have to train your classifier. Cross validation is a way to improve the training process. So basically, you method "cross_val_predict" trains it. So you're doing it right. But with only one feature, you classifier is lost, he just tells you that all is True when it's not the case. You need to give him more features to learn how to recognize plagiarism.